# CUBA : entity inheritance

Tags: cuba-platform

Provided sample 'Entity Inheritance' has the following entity model:
- Customer
- Company extends Customer
- Person extends Customer
- Order

The OrderEdit screen show how to handle the inheritance for fields associated with a Customer that could be a Company or a Person. This is perfectly clear.

However, edit screens for Company and Person do not take inheritance into account : they simply duplicate 'email' field which is commonly inherited from Customer.

Given all inputs I had at this point, if I had to design these screens I would propose the following way.

1) CustomerEditFrame : with the email field, no datasource defined

2) PersonEditScreen:
- Person datasource
- map lastName and firstName fields on Person datasource
- embed CustomerEditFrame
- inject Person datasource in the CustomerEditFrame

3) CompanyEditScreen:
- Company datasource
- map industry field to Company datasource
- embed CustomerEditFrame
- inject Company datasource in the CustomerEditFrame

Then the CustomerEditFrame is responsible for editing the subset of fields it is aware of in a datasource referring either of the two subclasses. Would this design work ?

For the sake of completeness of documentation I think this should be covered by the sample, as it is common case. In addition, it would be a good sample for frame manipulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right that screens should take entity inheritance into account to eliminate duplication of code. I've forked the sample project [here](https://github.com/knstvk/sample-entity-inheritance) to demonstrate how it can be done using frames.

`customer-frame.xml` contains fields of the base entity and a datasource for it:

```xml
<window xmlns="http://schemas.haulmont.com/cuba/window.xsd"
        caption="msg://editCaption"
        class="com.company.entityinheritance.gui.customer.CustomerFrame"
        focusComponent="fieldGroup"
        messagesPack="com.company.entityinheritance.gui.customer">
    <dsContext>
        <datasource id="customerDs"
                    class="com.company.entityinheritance.entity.Customer"
                    view="_local"/>
    </dsContext>
    <layout spacing="true">
        <fieldGroup id="fieldGroup"
                    datasource="customerDs">
            <column width="250px">
                <field id="name"/>
                <field id="email"/>
            </column>
        </fieldGroup>
    </layout>
</window>
```

In the `CustomerFrame` controller there is a public method to set an instance to the datasource:

```java
public class CustomerFrame extends AbstractFrame {

    @Inject
    private Datasource<Customer> customerDs;

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        customerDs.setItem(customer);
    }
}
```

The Company editor `company-edit.xml` includes the frame instead of Customer fields:

```xml
<window xmlns="http://schemas.haulmont.com/cuba/window.xsd"
        caption="msg://editCaption"
        class="com.company.entityinheritance.gui.company.CompanyEdit"
        datasource="companyDs"
        focusComponent="customerFrame"
        messagesPack="com.company.entityinheritance.gui.company">
    <dsContext>
        <datasource id="companyDs"
                    class="com.company.entityinheritance.entity.Company"
                    view="_local"/>
    </dsContext>
    <layout expand="windowActions"
            spacing="true">
        <frame id="customerFrame"
               screen="demo$Customer.frame"/>
        <fieldGroup id="fieldGroup"
                    datasource="companyDs">
            <column width="250px">
                <field id="industry"/>
            </column>
        </fieldGroup>
        <frame id="windowActions"
               screen="editWindowActions"/>
    </layout>
</window>
```

In the Company editor controller, the frame is injected and an edited instance is passed to it:

```java
public class CompanyEdit extends AbstractEditor<Company> {

    @Inject
    private CustomerFrame customerFrame;

    @Override
    protected void postInit() {
        customerFrame.setCustomer(getItem());
    }
}
```